# In Swift 2.0 what is the maximum length of a string?

Tags: ios, string, swift, string-length, maxlength

I have an application which utilizes a single string. This string contains data loaded from an array and then the string is exported to a text file.

My question is what is the longest length possible for this string, and when does it become a problem that it is getting too long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the [official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html):

> String is bridged to Objective-C as NSString, and a String that
>   originated in Objective-C may store its characters in an NSString.

Since all devices were capable of running iOS are 32 bit, this means [`NSUIntegerMax`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSIntegerMax) is 2^32.

According to [Swift opensource GitHub repo](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/String.swift) It would seem that its value is 2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 ; hexadecimal 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF for the 64 bit devices, following this code:

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif

// + (instancetype)
    //     stringWithCharacters:(const unichar *)chars length:(NSUInteger)length
...
maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxBufferCount
...
```

**TEST**: (on iPhone 6)

[image]

Comment: Whait what? It's 64 Bit on iPhone 5S and up!

Comment: Sure, you have reason, I forgot the NSUInteger conversion to int for 32 bit and long to 64bit, ok answer update.

Answer (score 5):

`String` is bridged to Objective-C as `NSString`, and a `String`
that originated in Objective-C may store its characters in an
`NSString`.  Since any arbitrary subclass of `NSString` can
become a `String`, there are no guarantees about representation or
efficiency in this case.

What is the maximum length of an `NSString` object?

The hard limit for `NSString` would be `NSUIntegerMax` characters. `NSUIntegerMax` is 2^32 - 1 and `NSString` can hold a little over 4.2 billion characters.

According comments:
for iPhone 5S and above since they are 64 Bit. It's 2^(64 - 1)

Comment: Note that 4 billion characters would amount to over 4 GB of memory, which would be a lot for any system. Xcode is using the most memory on my Activity Monitor right now, at 2 GB of memory for the entire application.

Comment: It's 2^(64 - 1) for iPhone 5S and above since they are 64 Bit. Just testet it on my 6S and 4S.